# Why doesn't this friend function allow brace-init-list but the static one does?

Tags: c++, friend, list-initialization

Basically this code won't compile

```cpp
struct M
{
    static void staticF(M m) {}
    friend void friendF(M m) {}
};

int main()
{
    M::staticF({}); //< okay
    M m;
    friendF(m); //< okay
    friendF({}); //< error: doesn't the compiler allow this?
}
```

The compiler says that `friendF` "is not declared in the scope".

Try the code: https://godbolt.org/z/8Mq664

Comment: Did you intend to use the *hidden friend* idiom?

Comment: @Eljay Not intended. I didn't even know what it was

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not the `{}`, but as the compiler says: The function is not declared in the scope where you try to call it. Add a declaration:

```
struct M
{
    static void staticF(M m) {}
    friend void friendF(M m) {}
};

void friendF(M m);

int main()
{
    M::staticF({}); //< okay
    M m;
    friendF(m); //< okay
    friendF({}); //< okay
}
```

The reason `friendF(m);` also worked without the declaration is [Argument Dependent Lookup (ADL)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl). In a nutshell: The compiler looks for `friendF` based on where its parameter is declared.

Note the typically the friend declaration is only the declaration and the definition is usually provided outside of the class:

```
struct M
{
    static void staticF(M m) {}
    void friendF(M m);
};

void friendF(M m) {}
```

If the function is only used in the scope of the class then it can be a private member.

Comment: Thanks! I will go with `void friendF(M m);` in the class and `void friendF(M m) {}` outside. However, I wanted all this to be in a header, so I though about using inline. I'm not sure if I should use `inline` in both declaration+definition or just in the definition.

Comment: @tuket: You can go the reverse way, define (and so declare) in class, and also add declaration outside of the class.

Comment: @tuket • If you want `friendF` to be declared-and-defined in the header, then `inline` for the implementing definition is the way to do it.  (Or vice versa, with an implicit inline.)

Comment: @tuket what jarod said. Read "typically" and "usually" with a grain of salt. I don't see big advantage/disadantage of either two options in the answer (and yes, you need `inline` when you put the definition in the header)

Comment: Awesome, both approches seem to work with templated functions as well

Answer (score 4):

try this way

```
struct M
{
    static void staticF(M m) {}
    friend void friendF(M m);
};

void friendF(M m) {}

int main()
{
    M::staticF({}); //< okay
    M m;
    friendF(m); //< okay
    friendF({}); //< okay
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`friend` functions use similar rules than [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

so your function is only found when type `M` is provided.

`{}` has no types.

Possible solution is to declare the function outside the class:

```
struct M
{
    static void staticF(M m) {}
    friend void friendF(M m) {}
};
void friendF(M m); // Now visible from outside
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6b2110ba63f83fd5)

Comment: I've seen lots of SO question with weird compiler problems when friend function was defined inside class it was friend to.